# It is possible to have two functions with the same name in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

hey just new to kotlin from java and i want to ask if is possible to have two functions with the same name , for example i have a function name is " PrintVal " i want at least to make a three of this without to change the name how can doing this in kotlin

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: i am new to kotlin i am 13 year old and can't by a books or courses from web bro

Comment: yes we can read about overloading in programming

Comment: and i will remove -1 to encourage you >> this is not the right place for these kinds of questions

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/method-overloading

Comment: A free kotlin book. Please check  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-pdf.html

Comment: @ocos looks bad not like udemy courses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can this way called overloading

[Check this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html)

Overloading refers to the ability to use a single identifier to define multiple methods of a class that differ in their input and output parameter make your functions but just change the parameter ( you should have a parameters)

Example :

```
   fun printVal(a : Int , b : Int){

        println(a+b)
    }

    fun printVal(a : Float , b: Float){

        println(a + b)
    }
```

Comment: With overloaded methods, the inputs change but the output does not necessarily have to change as well. For example, fun addNumbers(a : String , b: String) : Int and addNumbers(a : Int , b: Int) : Int could produce the same value.

Comment: @JayLin code work thanx but can i do without parameters

Comment: @Tom Levi Yes, of course. fun addNumbers() : Int would also be considered an overloaded method. The numbers being added could be set via a constructor or some other method.